# Change visibility of div when option is changed inside dropbox

Tags: javascript, html

I got codes like this inside my php:

```
<section id="placeOrder">
<h2>Place order</h2>
Your details
Customer Type: 
<select name="customerType">
    <option value="">Customer Type?</option>
    <option value="ret">Customer</option>
    <option value="trd">Trade</option>
</select>
```

and these are the divs of which visibility has to be changed according to the selected option:

```
<div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails">
    Forename <input type="text" name="forename" id="forename" />
    Surname <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" />
</div>
<div id="tradeCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="visibility:hidden">
    Company Name <input type="text" name="companyName" id="companyName" />
</div>
```

I tried this javascript:

```
<script>
document.getElementsByName("customerType").onchange = function () {
    var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("tradeCustDetails").style.visibility = (val == "trd") ? "visible" : "hidden";
    document.getElementById("retCustDetails").style.visibility = (val == "trd") ? "hidden" : "visible";
};
</script>
```

But div `tradecustdetails"` does not appear and div `retCustDetails` is still on there.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why is this tagged as Java?

Comment: my bad, i was happened to type java script but instead java appear

Comment: OK, understood, thanks for removing it.

Comment: Correctly tagged questions will get more views by folks that are able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your script, this should work.

```
<script>
     function jsFunction() {
         var val =  document.getElementById("dropSelect").options[document.getElementById("dropSelect").selectedIndex].value;
         document.getElementById("tradeCustDetails").style.visibility = (val == "trd") ? "visible" : "hidden";
         document.getElementById("retCustDetails").style.visibility = (val == "trd") ? "hidden" : "visible";
     }
</script>
```

Update your dropdown HTML as well.

```
<select id="dropSelect" name="customerType" onchange="jsFunction()">
```

**EDIT #1: using getElementsByName()**

```
function jsFunction() {
     var val =  document.getElementsByName("customerType")[0];
     val = val.options[val.selectedIndex].value;                    
     document.getElementById("tradeCustDetails").style.visibility = (val == "trd") ? "visible" : "hidden";
     document.getElementById("retCustDetails").style.visibility = (val == "trd") ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
```

Comment: well its working. But, can i use getElementsByName instead of getElementById?

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByName()` returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified name. Hence you have to loop through them like this:

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("customerType");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    // do something with x[i]
}
```

If you are using only one select element, then it is better to use `getElementById()` like this:

**HTML**

```
<select id="customerType" name="customerType">
    <option value="">Customer Type?</option>
    <option value="ret">Customer</option>
    <option value="trd">Trade</option>
</select>
```

**Script**

```
document.getElementById("customerType").onchange = function () {
    var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("tradeCustDetails").style.visibility = (val == "trd") ? "visible" : "hidden";
    document.getElementById("retCustDetails").style.visibility = (val == "trd") ? "hidden" : "visible";
};
```